# compare 2 records but it won't compare

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code that has to control 2 records from my database.

If `total_rows` is smaller then `allowed` it has to add the user. Otherwise it has to show a message.

If i use `<=` it works but it allows everything and when i use `<` it won't work.

My question is why it won't work?

PS: It does not give an error because it is in another document then the html

This is my code:

```
$allowed = "SELECT 
    `allowed_users` AS allowed 
  FROM 
    `partner_subscriptions` 
  WHERE
    `user_id` = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";

$row = mysqli_num_rows($allowed);
$count = "SELECT 
    COUNT(`user_id`) 
  AS 
    total_rows 
  FROM 
    users 
  WHERE 
    org_id = '".$_POST['org']."'";

$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($count);

if ($row2['total_rows'] <= $row['allowed'])
{ 
    $q = "UPDATE 
        `organisations` 
      SET 
        `current_users` = `current_users` + 1 
      WHERE 
        `org_id`='".$_POST['org']."'";

    $sql = "UPDATE 
       `users` 
      SET 
        `active`= 1, 
        `type` = 0 
      WHERE 
        `user_id` = '" . $_POST['user'] . "'";

      if ($conn->query($sql) && $conn->query($q) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";

    } else {

      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

    }
}
else
{
    throw new Exception('Limit reached');
}
```

Comment: @scaisEdge my data is okay. `total_rows` is 3 and `allowed` is like 1500

Comment: Watch out for SQL Injection. Never use `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` directly in SQL statement.

Comment: Have you tried to dump these two variables? What **exactly** does `$row` contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just get count_row for $allowed  not the content

try using mysqli_fetch_array

```
$allowed = "SELECT `allowed_users` AS allowed FROM `partner_subscriptions` 
    WHERE `user_id` = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($your_conn, $allowed);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

$count = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) AS total_rows FROM users WHERE org_id = '".$_POST['org']."'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($your_conn, $count);

$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

if ($row2['total_rows'] <= $row['allowed'])
```

Comment: it does the same as i have now. it won't work if  this`<=` is this `<` and it does not go to the else when i change my data

Comment: is `$allowed` ever executed? he never uses `mysqli_query()` before calling `mysqli_num_rows()`

Comment: what is the `$r`?

Comment: I've also noticed that his question is all over the place

Comment: @scaisEdge and it has to be `mysqli_query()` instead of `mysql_query` right?

Comment: check my answer in a second

Comment: @KebabProgrammer what answer?

Comment: @scaisEdge, you cannot use `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` together, as `mysql_*` is deprecated

Comment: @scaisEdge in `$result2` `$allowed` has to be `$count` right?

Comment: @xmastertje   .. correct . answer  update ..  (today..is not my day .. )

Comment: @scaisEdge haha no problem happy enough that you are helping me out

Comment: @xmastertje  I'm doing too many things together and it's not the best way to do them

Comment: @KebabProgrammer  thanks  ..  but not "nothings"  .. as yiu can see

Comment: @xmastertje np m8, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$allowed = "SELECT `allowed_users` AS allowed FROM `partner_subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$row = mysqli_num_rows($allowed);
$count = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) AS total_rows FROM users WHERE org_id = '".$_POST['org']."'";
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($count);
```

I've noticed in your code above that you are never calling the method `mysqli_query()` in here, you were just creating your string queries but not executing them. Which means PHP is most likely not initializing `$row` and `$row2`

You can declare them in two ways Shown below:

```
$allowed = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `allowed_users` AS allowed FROM `partner_subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($allowed);
$count = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) AS total_rows FROM users WHERE org_id = '".$_POST['org']."'");
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($count);
```

OR

```
$allowed = "SELECT `allowed_users` AS allowed FROM `partner_subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$result_allowed = mysqli_query($connection, $allowed);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($allowed);

$count = "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) AS total_rows FROM users WHERE org_id = '".$_POST['org']."'";
$result_count = mysqli_query($connection, $count);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_count);
```

Comment: In your code, probably because `$row2['total_rows']` and `$row['allowed']` were never set in the first place

Comment: Since you said if total rows is less than allowed, why then are you using `($row2['total_rows'] <= $row['allowed'])` instead of ($row2['total_rows'] < $row['allowed'])